# WiFi range is getting worse

Tags: wireless

If I start up my laptop (EEE PC 701 running Lubuntu 14.10) my WiFi is normal, but every minute is the range 1% badder. And that's very annoying. If I use my laptop an hour, I have to restart it to have access to the internet. How can I fix that?

[Link to wireless info (ubuntu paste)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10785822/)

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. Run it once just after booting and once or twice at different intervals to show the symptoms of the performance degradation.

Comment: I have run the WiFi diagnostics and added a link to my wireless info. Can you look at it now???

Comment: [Here's a suggestion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221012&p=13015464#post13015464) to disable hardware encryption: disable WiFi, then run `modprobe -r ath5k && modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt=1`, re-enable WiFi.

Comment: I have executed that modprobe command with sudo, but how do you normally re-enable WiFi? I ask that because if I want to re-enable that I have to unblock it using "sudo rfkill unblock wlan; sudo rfkil unblock wifi" and then I can re-enable the WiFi, otherwise I can't re-enable the WiFi...

Comment: Now my WiFi have faster less range...

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: The alternative is to create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/ath5k-fix.conf` with the content `options ath5k nohwcrypt=1` and reboot. Same effect, but persistent across reboots and therefore no hassle with manual module reloading.

Comment: Must I do that with `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k-fix.conf` or with `nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k-fix.conf`?

Comment: You need super-user privileges (e. g. with `sudo`) to create files in the directory.